# Python continue function wont start the code all over again

Tags: python

I am trying to start the whole code again but it restarts the current loop can someone help?

````
while guessp1 & guessp2 != answer:
        if guessp1 == answer:
            print(player1, " won!")
            while True:
                answers = str(input("Play again? (y/n): "))
                if answers in ("y","n"):
                    break
                print('invalid input.')
            if answers == "y":
                continue
                
            else:
                quit()```
````

Comment: For starters, in your words, what do you think this statement is doing? `while guessp1 & guessp2 != answer`

Comment: its creating a loop

Comment: You need to show us _the whole code_. In general, this is the point of the `continue` statement to _restart the current loop_. The rest of the code probably needs to be included in the loop in order to make it work. But it is hard to guess if the rest is not known.

Comment: Apologies for the late post. I've provided a working solution below which can be modified to suit your program.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the posted code, which are addressed later in this answer. For a start, a working example (which can be modified to your liking) is posted below.

#### Key elements:

- An outer loop as a simple `While True` which will continue to execute until a `break` statement is reached (within its scope).
- A single 'Play again?' prompt, nested into an inner `while` loop, courtesy of the new (Python 3.8+) [walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/).

#### Example:

```
p1 = 'Terry' 
answer = 'spam'

while True:
    guess = input('\nWhat goes with eggs? ')
    if guess == answer:
        print(f'{p1} won!')
        while (resp := input('Play again? [y|n] ').lower()) not in ('y', 'n'):
            print('Invalid input.')
        if resp != 'y':
            break
    else:
        print('Sorry, try again.')
```

---

#### Code issues:

- The first `while` statement mixes a [bitwise AND](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#bitwise-and) and a logical difference operators. Given the variables involved, this will not work.
- Additionally, the first `while` loop is [evaluated as](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) `while ((guessp1 & guessp2) != answer)` which is not only not the desired evaluation as this will always evaluate to `False`, unless the value of `answer` is `True` or `False`, but will also throw an `unsupported operand` error due to the attempted bitwise operation on strings.
- Once this is fixed (as `while True`), the loop runs infinitely as we aren't provided with all of the variable definitions from the code proceeding this block. Therefore, debugging stopped here.